# Nginx causes redirects when server root is changed

Tags: nginx

My nginx version is :

```
root@v-enterprise15:/etc/nginx/conf.d# nginx -v
nginx: nginx version: nginx/1.0.5
```

My application is installed at

```
/usr/share/nginx/www/magento/current
```

When I access

```
http://{my_server}:81/magento/current/index.php
```

it works fine. This is because the server root is set to `/usr/share/nginx/www`;

Now I want to acces the app using `http://{myserver}:81/index.php`.
When I change the server root to `/usr/share/nginx/www/magento/current` and type the above URL, it REDIRECTS with http 302 to

```
http://{my_server}:81/magento/current
```

What might be the reason for this?

It then applies other rules from my .conf and gives a 404.

I see this in the access log:

```
[31/Jul/2012:11:19:23 +0530] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; en) Presto/2.10.229 Version/11.64"
```

My .conf file is:

```
server {
    listen 81 default;
## SSL directives might go here
    server_name {my_server};
    #root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/magento/current;
    error_log /var/log/nginx.error.log notice;
    access_log /var/log/nginx.access.log ;

    rewrite_log on;


    location / {
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @magehandler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        #try_files $uri $uri/ ; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        #expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }


    location ^~  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }

    location @magehandler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        #rewrite / /index.php;
        rewrite ^(.*) index.php$1 last;
    }

    #The more-specific regex are at the top.
    #The regex's are evaluated in the order in which they appear.
    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        #if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
            proxy_read_timeout 120;
            proxy_connect_timeout 120;
        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    }
    location ~ /(media|skin|js)/ { }
    location ~ /(tag|admin|customer|wishlist|checkout|catalog|app).*$ { #store URL
            rewrite /(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ /[a-zA-Z]+$ { #store URL
            rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z]+) ?store=$1 last;
    }
    location ~ /[a-zA-Z]+/ { #store URL
            rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z]+)(.*) /$2?store=$1 last;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not any redirects in your nginx config, then it is most likely that redirect caused by your application.